# remove location updates with a locationClient

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I've got a Google Maps activity in my Android app, and *I'm receiving location updates endlessly*. I want to remove location updates, but I don't really know how to do it, I've searched on Google but I haven't found anything helpfull, probably because I made it in a (?) weird way. I'll explain myself with my app code:

I've got a FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient declared:

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient;
```

Which I later instantiate:

```
locationClient = getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

Then, I request the last location like this:

```
locationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if(location != null){
                        userPosition = location;
                        locationClient.removeLocationUpdates();
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            });
```

That's in maps "my location" button, and it gives me constant location updates, which prevents me from moving the map, because if I try to, it automatically moves back to my location.

How should I stop those location updates? I know the removeLocationUpdates method, but I don't have a GoogleApiClient object nor a locationCallback object, and I don't know how to do this.

Hope you can help me mates, I've been searching for a couple of hours by now.

Thank you very much in advantage!

Comment: You must at least have instance of `LocationCallback` in order to remove location updates.

Comment: Is `onSuccess()` calling every time when location got changed?

Comment: However `.getLastLocation()` method provides a simplified way to get location. It is particularly well suited for applications that do not require an accurate location and that **do not want to maintain extra logic for location updates**.

Comment: I instanced LocationCallback, but I don't know exactly what to do with that instance...
And I guess onSuccess() is called every time location changes, because is constantly pointing at my location...
Thank you for your help Wizard! I've gotta go home now, but anything you reply or anything you need, I'll post tomorrow. Again, thank you very very much!

Comment: Again Wizard, thank you very much for your replies. I don't know exactly why, but my .getLastLocation() is constantly giving me my location. I'm gonna check the Intents whole code, maybe i'm looping that piece or code or something, anyways, I'd thank you if you give me more info about LocationCallback, how should I implement it to remove location updates... Thank you very very much!

Comment: Okay, I fixed it, I was calling getLastLocation again in another method, which I called from getLastLocation, and it was looping getting my location, I'm just stupid. Thank you very much Wizard!

Comment: Cool. Keep pushing yourself! haha..

Comment: BTW. You can get current location directly from `GoogleMap` without using `FusedClient`.

Comment: How? That would be nice to know!

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why are you getting location using FusedClient if you already got `GoogleMap` in your screen. Because you can get your current location directly from `GoogleMap` instance;

Suppose you have an instance of `GoogleMap` -> `mMap`. To get updates you just need to register callback:

```
Location mLocation = mMap.getMyLocation(); // mLocation is your current location
```

*However, this method is [deperecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getMyLocation()).*

Here is how better how can do it (Taken from [official guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location)):-

```
public class MyLocationDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        OnMyLocationClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {

  private GoogleMap mMap;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
        (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    // TODO: Before enabling the My Location layer, you must request
    // location permission from the user. This sample does not include
    // a request for location permission.
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
    // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could find such an easy answer before, thank you very much, really!

Comment: Well, What we say it..? Better late than Never!